# How to use PowerPoint templates as theme in Data Studio?

Tags: powerpoint, looker-studio

I want to create a `dashboard` on `Google Data Studio` using a template provided by my organization but I can't find any helpful resource to do that so I'm tempted to think that's not even possible. I tried to use "Extract theme for image" option in GDS but didn't work properly since it just tries to emulate the colors from the image and not the template itself.
Any advice or suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve this.

Although last versions of Google Data Studio contains resources to allow it to present dashboards as it were a presentation software, I don't think it is intended to offer advanced resources for this task, neighter make it compatible with other presentation softwares (especially if you're talking about third party software, as Microsoft PowerPoint).

The best you can do is to create your own dashboard, and try to mimic your company's provided template.

Answer (score 0):

you could also use an image as theme, it will at least uses the colors of you company as you can see in the image below[image].

And that's unfortunally what you can do with it, and for powerpoint themes, you could also use Microsoft Power bi which is way more advanced that Google Data studio